# AngularJS directive: attr with name of other directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

A simple example to explain my case:

I have a directive for labels

```
<input label="{{obj.label}}"/>
```

But for some other directives I want to use an attribute with name "label"

```
<other-directive label="My label"></other-directive>
```

just as an attribute, not processing the label-directive.

I could just rename the attribute to e.g. "my-label":

```
<other-directive my-label="My label"></other-directive>
```

but it would be nice to use "label" as an attribute name.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible... One thing you can do is `restrict` your directive to something besides attribute, which is not ideal either.  You could, for example, `restrict: "E"`, where you'd do `<label>{{obj.label}}</label>` and then angular would ignore `<other-directive label="">`

Comment: @chrise: And how is Angular supposed to distinguish which `label`s you mean as directives and which as plain attributes ?

Comment: @Tom No, sorry. This is no solution. The label is just an example, could be any other name for an attribute vs. directive.

Comment: @ExpertSystem That's my question. How to tell angular: "This is not a directive here, it's only an attribute". Maybe it didn't make much sense try to name an attribute like a directive.

Comment: @chrise: Yes, but you need to tell us how to distinguish the two cases (what are the criteria for being interpreted as a directive), so we can tell you how to tell Angular.

Comment: @ExpertSystem: Being attribute on "other-directive" -> Attribute. Being attribute on any other element -> Directive. So the "other-directive" knows that label should be treated like an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ExpertSystem points out in the comments to the question, angular really has no way of knowing out of the box whether your directive should be applied in one case versus another.  The only way I can think of to get around this is to include logic in your directive's compile function that knows how to determine whether it should be applied or not.  [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zMp5aj4ZLjDz9NZrGw4l?p=preview) demonstrates how I would accomplish this.  You basically need to return two different link functions from the compilation phase; one if your directive should be applied (in this case adding a label before the input), and a different one if it should be skipped.  You are then free to use that as an argument to a separate directive.  This may not work if your directive needs to do things like transclusion  or isolated scopes (things that angular doesn't like two directives on the same element to do).

I'd be very sparing with how you use this, however, as it will create an inconsistent API for other developers who may be working with this code.  They may not know when the directive will apply and when it won't.

Comment: Thank you. This is really a good point: "it will create an inconsistent API". For that reason I should use a different name, making it clear to other developers (which is important for me).